# Copying rotated image to existing image in C# code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation

I am trying to copy a rotated image to an existing image in the code-behind.

Here are my 2 images:

```
<Image x:Name="tempImage1" Source="Images/firstImage.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
<Image x:Name="myImage2" Source="Images/secondImage.jpg" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

And the rotation in the code-behind:

```
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(-theta, 200, 300);
tempImage1.RenderTransform = rt;
myImage2.Source = tempImage1.Source;
```

I know I'm not doing it right (still very new to this). Could someone please help point me in the right direction? The result I'm looking for is to have myImage2 have show tempImage1 in its **rotated** form, not the original source.

Comment: Meanwhile you should have realized that it won't work this way. What you probably could do is to render a rotated Image control into a RenderTargetBitmap.

Comment: Clemens, can I get you to put what you just wrote above as an answer? I just tried the RenderTargetBitmap and it works perfectly!

Comment: You could as well write the answer yourself, with the relevant parts of the code that solved your problem. That may be more helpful for others than just giving an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Using a RenderTargetBitmap solved the issue for me.

With images `tempImage1` and `myImage2` in your XAML:

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(_width, _height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(tempImage1);
myImage2.Source = rtb;
```

The above is done with the assumption that `tempImage1` has already been rotated and transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do that you must know that the first image would be visible as it is in the background  well I simply rotated as per your question in an angle of 30 degree the XAML remains same the new C# code is

```
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
rt.Angle = 30;
tempImage1.RenderTransform = rt;
myImage2.Source = tempImage1.Source;
```

Comment: Oh oops I had meant myImage2 in my original code. For some reason though, tempImage1 is transferring the original untouched image, not the rotated.

Comment: When you are setting the Source of Image2 to tempimage.Source then all its properties are copied i.e from the rotation transform along with the source even. I thought thats what you wanted. Or do you just want to rotate image 2 only?
If thats the case then just write
`RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(-theta, 200, 300);
myImage2.RenderTransform = rt;`    No need to set source

Comment: I'm trying to rotate myImage2, but because I have an opacity  LinearGradientBrush on myImage2, it will rotate too because the entire X,Y axis will rotate with a RenderTransform. So my logic is to rotate tempImage1 and set it as myImage2's source. That way, I keep the gradient brush untouched while rotating an image.

Comment: Well there's the flaw when you set source of image2 to image1 then all of its properties gets overridden including the opacity/LinearGradientBrush one. You would need to now elaborate with exact code as to what you want. from what I understood why dont you try transforming image 1 and place a rectangle instead of image2 you can set LinearGradient on rectangle and rotate the image as you want.

Comment: Here's my full code posted a month ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585378/wpf-rotating-image-with-arbitrary-angle There's that gradient brush, but it goes from left to right. If I rotate the image, the gradient will go at (theta) degrees. So doing a bit of research, the only easy way is to do that image.source transfer. But of course, I'm still very new and just starting CS at University, so I may have misinformed myself.

Comment: why dont you try the rectangle method set gradient on rectangle and rotate your image. Then your gradient wont rotate and only your image will

Comment: I started doing the rectangle method, but I just realized - I have more than 1 image (as shown in my full code), so the rectangle won't work, because I'll only be seeing 1 image.